# Check user entered text aginst xml

Tags: actionscript-3

i am trying to check user entered text in a dynamic text box against a XML file, so if the user enters the it traces jackpot and the array no its stored at is stored, this is what i have so far but cant get it to work, anyone have any ideas ? all that is on the stage is a dynamic text box called userID  and a button called idBtn to check, thanks

EDIT : i changed it around, what i cant get to work is the comparison between the user entered text and what is in the xml, the if loop always runs through even when true,

```
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.text.TextField;

 var xmlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 var xmlreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("users.xml");
 xmlloader.load(xmlreq);

 xmlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, convertdata);

 function convertdata(event:Event)
     {
     var xmlinfo:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
     var postedlist:XMLList = xmlinfo.user;
     var totallist:Number = postedlist.length();
     trace(totallist);
     for(var i:int=0 ; i < totallist ; i++)
         {
             trace("id_no[i] before lowered " + xmlinfo.user.id_no[i])
             xmlinfo.user.id_no[i] = xmlinfo.user.id_no[i].toLowerCase();
             trace("id_no[i] after lowered " + xmlinfo.user.id_no[i])
         }

         function checkUser(event:MouseEvent):void
             {
                 for(var i:int=0 ; i < totallist ; i++)
                 {
                     var enteredID:String = userId.text
                     enteredID = enteredID.toLowerCase();
                     trace("before if "+ xmlinfo.user.id_no[i] +" and " + enteredID)
                 if (xmlinfo.user.id_no[i]==enteredID)
                     {
                     trace("jackpot");
                     }
                 else
                     {
                     trace("nope");
                     }
                 }

             }
         idBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, checkUser);
     }
```

my xml is just

```
<root>
   <user>
        <id_no>a</id_no>
        <username>Jane Doe</username>
        <banned>-1</banned>
        <equip_out>-1</equip_out>
    </user>
</root>
```

my output is :

```
 1
 id_no[i] before lowered a
 id_no[i] after lowered a
```

with noting entered in text-box

```
      before if a and 

      nope
```

with q entered in text-box

```
      before if a and q

      nope
```

with a entered in text box (this is what i want to return the jackpot trace at)

```
      before if a and a

      nope
```

Comment: What do you mean you "cant get it to work"? You'll need to be more specific than that, does it give any error messages? And why do you have a function within a loop? Also your XML seems to be incomplete, you need opening `<user>` and `<root>` tags.

Comment: Apologies, i updated what i meant and changed around the actionscrip

Comment: Please post your output

Comment: Posted them there, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're comparing an XML with a String.

Try this:

```
if (xmlinfo.user.id_no[i].toString()==enteredID)
{
   trace("jackpot");
}
else
{
   trace("nope");
}
```

Comment: @user2367312 Be sure to click the check mark on the left to mark this as the accepted answer. Upvoting doesn't hurt either ;)

Comment: sorry, did that there, says i cant upvote till i have 15 rep though, thanks again